# Echo text based off of dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using Magento and using Custom Options. I have 5 custom options that allow the user to choose the condition of the item. I want some text below to show what the condition means when they select it.

Im sorry for the confusion. I want this to update live on the screen when the appropriate option is selected.

Here is my current code but it isn't displaying the text.

```
    <select name="options[1][]" id="select_1" class="multiselect required-entry product-custom-option" title=""  onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
<option value="1"  price="0" >Perfect </option>
<option value="2"  price="-35" >Excellent </option>
<option value="3"  price="-105" >Good </option>
<option value="4"  price="-140" >Poor </option>
<option value="5"  price="-252" >Broken </option></select>

   <?php if( $_POST['select_1']=='1' ){
                echo "Perfect Condition Text";

                }elseif( $_POST['select_1']=='2' ){
                echo "Excellent Condition Text";

                }elseif( $_POST['select_1']=='3' ){
                echo "Good Condition Text";

                }elseif( $_POST['select_1']=='4' ){
                echo "Poor Condition Text";

                }elseif( $_POST['select_1']=='5' ){
                echo "Broken Condition Text";

                } ?>
```

Comment: Do you wish for it to happen 'live' (i.e. without submitting the form? You'll need JavaScript for that, not PHP.

Comment: Yes, Live. Can you direct me to some code that would help with that I am terrible with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the value of the `<select>` without refreshing the page then you could use javascript or jquery. Here is a sample of Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function displayCondition() {
    condition = new Array("", "Perfect", "Excellent", "Good", "Poor", "Broken");
    var getsel = document.getElementById('select_1').value;
    document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formName">
    <select name="options[1][]" id="select_1" class="multiselect required-entry product-custom-option" title=""  onchange="displayCondition()">
        <option value="0">Select Condition</option>
        <option value="1"  price="0" >Perfect</option>
        <option value="2"  price="-35" >Excellent</option>
        <option value="3"  price="-105" >Good</option>
        <option value="4"  price="-140" >Poor</option>
        <option value="5"  price="-252" >Broken</option>
    </select>
    <div id="divId" name="divName" ></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Jordan Above shows displaying live, I'm not sure how you want to display so I put it in an `input` field

Comment: I want to display text in another div.
So if Perfect is selected. The text in the div will reflect the predefined text for something that is perfect. Also I can not change anything with the select area. It is generated by Magento and I am currently unsure where.

Comment: I modified my answer, however without being able to call this function it will not work. Meaning, the only thing you would NEED to change is the `onchange="displayCondition()"`

Comment: can I put multiple onchange's in one select?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `<select>` name to `select_1` will solve your problem:

```
<select name="select_1" id="select_1" class="multiselect required-entry product-custom-option" title=""  onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
```

If you can't change the names for some reason, change `$_POST['select_1']` to `$_POST['options'][1][0]`

Comment: Can't change it, it is created by Magento. It creates them all dynamically.

Comment: Still nothing. I need it to refresh live. I was informed I need to research JS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The array will not be available in PHP `$_POST` by `select_1` index but PHP `$_POST` is going to have an `options` array `$_POST['options']`

Answer (score 0):

The post array name is based on the name of the form element, not the id of the form element. Change the name property of your select element to "select_1" and you will get what you are looking for.